# Get Yahoo email address using yahoo ID or yahoo guid?

Tags: yahoo-api

How to Get Yahoo email address using yahoo ID or yahoo guid?

I completed the yahoo API Outh to obtain the data of a user of Yahoo! Messenger, but can not directly send email to them, because there is no email address in the data, but there yahooid ...

```
e.g. yahooid => john123
```

If appending `@yahoo.com` to its *yahooid* field. As I see, this is totally wrong. Because with a yahooid, say `john123`, the associated email may have an international domain like `john123@yahoo.co.uk, john123@yahoo.com.vn` etc.

I can use yahooid to get his guid, using YQL:

```
select guid from yahoo.identity where yid='john123'
```

How to get Yahoo email address using yahoo ID or yahoo guid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By design, you can't get the Yahoo email address from either a Yahoo ID or GUID. In the early days you could usually infer that for a given id "yournamehere", the email address would be "yournamehere@yahoo.com". That's no longer a safe assumption in part due to the international domains as you mentioned, and to help prevent spammers.

Typically application or website developers would solve this by asking the user for their email address as part of the OAuth or OpenID authentication flow.

Answer (score 0):

Use YQL XML or JSON to get user's email (after user login) http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20social.profile%20where%20guid%20=%20me